# How do I print output values of generator functions?

Tags: python, generator

I'm trying to print the yield of a generator function that I get when using next().

I've defined a function as per this:

```
import itertools

sequence = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

def next_player(seq):
    yield itertools.cycle(seq)
```

Now, when I call the above function and use next() (for e.g. next(next_player(sequence))), what I get is the memory address (e.g. <itertools.cycle object at 0x7f9409fad440>).

How do I print the actual value within the list (e.g. 'a', 'b', etc.) instead. I know I can iterate over the generator object with a 'for' statement, but I was curious if there's another way to do this using next(), etc.

Comment: Did you mean: `return itertools.cycle(seq)`?

Comment: You want to use `yield` when you have to return multiple values in a for loop. It saves you from having to append to a list, for instance. Here you just need to return once, so you need `return`, which in this case is the same as `yield from`, since you're already returning a generator.

Answer (score 2):

You want you use `yield from`:

```
import itertools

sequence = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

def next_player(seq):
    yield from itertools.cycle(seq)

g = next_player(sequence)
for _ in range(6):
    print(next(g))
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
d
a
b
```

To elaborate: `yield from` can chain interables, in this case it's the same as writing:

```
def next_player(seq):
    for x in itertools.cycle(seq):
        yield x
```

but since `itertools.cycle` already returns a generator-like object, you could just write

```
def next_player(seq):
    return itertools.cycle(seq)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option you have is declare the cycle prior to your function:

```
from itertools import cycle
sequence = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
cycle_sequence = cycle(sequence)

def next_item():
    return next(cycle_sequence)
```

And then use it:

```
for _ in range(9):
    n = next_item()
    print(n)
```

will print:

```
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
d
a
```